# Check which UIScrollView is being scrolled?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm new to iOS development and I don't know how `scrollViewDidScroll` method works. I'm using the method to connect between `UIViewPager`(Top Image Slider in the screenshot) and `UIPageControl` as a tutorial said. But sadly, whenever I scroll `UICollectionViews`(Shoes in the screenshot) that method is being called and pageControl is effected unnecessarily. It will be great if I could differentiate which view is scrolled(`UIScrollView` or `UICollectionView`) inside the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

[image]

Here's `scrollViewDidScroll` method,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let total = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.width
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let percent = Double(offset / total)

    let progress = percent * Double(self.sliderImages.count - 1)
    pageControl.progress = progress
}
```

**Something strange** is that the parameter `scrollView` is always being the ScrollView(top one in the pic) even I scrolled UICollectionViews(Shoes in the pic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check which `scrollView` is being scrolled like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView === yourCollectionView {
        //Do something
    }
    //or you can use this
    if scrollView.isKind(of: UICollectionView.self) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `===` to test if two objects are the same object instead of `==`.  `===` does a pointer check, and `==` tests if their properties are all the same.

Comment: @vacawama I was just thinking of that and tested it out on my collection view and `==` works! Can you tell us an example where it wouldn't?

Comment: It's quite possible that equality for `UIViewControlers` just uses `===` under the hood.  In general they're not the same.  It is possible to construct an example such as `class Foo: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.bar == rhs.bar
    }

    var bar = 13
}` and show that `Foo() == Foo()` is `true`, but `Foo() === Foo()` is false.

Comment: `if scrollView is UICollectionView`

Comment: It works, but when I put a tag in my ScrollView. And I checked at Debug mode. I got the same tag. No idea why..